# Lightweight email client with synchronized IMAP folder and filter enable

Tags: windows, email-client, imap

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird for my daily works to read email. But I realize that there is too much memory it consumes. So I switch to Opera Mail. But it's not full featured like Thunderbird: There is no email filtered and no way to create IMAP folder that synchronized with server.

So what I need is a lightweight email client for Windows that equipped with full featured similar with that on Thunderbird.

Comment: I'm using claws-mail. It consumes about 80 mbytes.

Comment: http://www.claws-mail.org/win32/

Comment: @ayvango Would you mind posting a high quality answer recommending claws-mail?